# Access a variable's value inside, outside, or into another dataset?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

How do I access the value of a variable inside a dataset; outside a dataset or into another dataset?

I have a variable which counts the number of values in a dataset. I want to use this variable outside the list-component which refers to that dataset.
How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In older versions of iReport, Datasets didn't have the ability to "return" values. I'm not sure if it has been added in latest release.

On the other hand, Subreports do return values. You might want to check that.